# Difference between two way to init Akka Router

Tags: akka, actor

My system run with Play framework 2.5 and Akka build-in. I believe there are two ways to init a router.

1:

```
ActorRef router = akkaService.getActorSystem()
  .actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(poolSize)
  .props(Props.create(ProfileActor.class)), "ProfileActor");
```

2:

```
ActorRef router = akkaService.getActorSystem()
  .actorOf(new Props(ProfileActor.class)
  .withRouter( new RoundRobinRouter(poolSize)), "ProfileActor"));
```

So I have 2 questions:

- Are they different?
- Which way is better?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that number 1 is supported in the current version of Akka (2.4.x), whilst number 2 has been discontinued.

`RoundRobinRouter` is part of Akka 2.2.x, and has been first deprecated in Akka 2.3.x (see [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html#Routers)) and then removed in Akka 2.4.x.